# Group DataFrame by binning a column::Float64, in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

Say I have a `DataFrame` with a column of `Float64`s, I'd like to group the dataframe by binning that column. I hear the `cut` function might help, but it's not defined over dataframes. Some work has been done (https://gist.github.com/tautologico/3925372), but I'd rather use a library function rather than copy-pasting code from the Internet. Pointers?

**EDIT** Bonus karma for finding a way of doing this by month over UNIX timestamps :)

Comment: regarding UNIX timestamps, `df[:month] = Dates.month.(df[:timestamp])` works for me. `groupby(df, :month)` can later split the DataFrame according to the column.

Comment: That's more or less what I did, except I used so much more code… :)

Answer (score 2):

You could bin dataframes based on a column of `Float64`s like this. Here my bins are increments of 0.1 from 0.0 to 1.0, binning the dataframe based on a column of 100 random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
using DataFrames #load DataFrames
df = DataFrame(index = rand(Float64,100)) #Make a DataFrame with some random Float64 numbers
df_array = map(x->df[(df[:index] .>= x[1]) .& (df[:index] .<x[2]),:],zip(0.0:0.1:0.9,0.1:0.1:1.0)) #Map an anonymous function that gets every row between two numbers specified by a tuple called x, and map that anonymous function to an array of tuples generated using the zip function.
```

This will produce an array of 10 dataframes, each one with a different 0.1-sized bin.

As for the UNIX timestamp question, I'm not as familiar with that side of things, but after playing around a bit maybe something like this could work:

```
using Dates

df = DataFrame(unixtime = rand(1E9:1:1.1E9,100)) #Make a dataframe with floats containing pretend unix time stamps
df[:date] = Dates.unix2datetime.(df[:unixtime]) #convert those timestamps to DateTime types
df[:year_month] = map(date->string(Dates.Year.(date))*" "*string(Dates.Month.(date)),df[:date]) #Make a string for every month in your time range
df_array = map(ym->df[df[:year_month] .== ym,:],unique(df[:year_month])) #Bin based on each unique year_month string
```

Comment: There's a cut function in CategoricalArrays.jl https://juliadata.github.io/CategoricalArrays.jl/latest/using.html#CategoricalArrays.cut

Comment: @ian-marshall That's more or less what I ended up doing, except I operated on floored/truncated dates to the month granularity, similar to Dan's approach in the comment above, but more verbose.